# How to implement a custom String sequence identifier generator with JPA Jakarta

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have an entity named Product.

```java
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "product_seq")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "product_seq",
            strategy = "com.example.jpa.entity.StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "P"),
                    @Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%05d")
            })
    private String reference;

    private String description;

    // Constructor, getters and setters
}
```

I would like to generate two generated id in database with JPA (Hibernate) :

1 | P000001 | First Product Title
2 | P000002 | Second Product Title
...

I was thinking to use this implementation but didn't work (below)

How Can I implement the //TODO section with JPA (Hibernate 6+) ?

```java
public class StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

    public static final String VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER = "valuePrefix";
    public static final String VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT = "";
    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER = "numberFormat";
    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT = "%d";
    private String valuePrefix;
    private String numberFormat;

    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) throws MappingException {
        valuePrefix = ConfigurationHelper.getString(VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, params, VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT);
        numberFormat = ConfigurationHelper.getString(NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, params, NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT);
    }

    @Override
    public Object generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        // TODO : get generated id and concat it with "P_"
        return null;
    }

}
```

All posts I found are using old versions and not working, like [here](https://thorben-janssen.com/custom-sequence-based-idgenerator/)

Answer (score 1):

Solution can be this implementation :

```java
public class StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

    public static final String VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER = "valuePrefix";
    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER = "numberFormat";

    private String valuePrefix;
    private String numberFormat;

    private static final String VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT = "";
    private static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT = "%d";

    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) throws MappingException {
        valuePrefix = ConfigurationHelper.getString(VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, params, VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT);
        numberFormat = ConfigurationHelper.getString(NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, params, NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT);
    }

    @Override
    public Object generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        String query = String.format("select %s from %s", session.getEntityPersister(object.getClass().getName(), object)
                        .getIdentifierPropertyName(),
                object.getClass().getSimpleName());

        Stream<String> ids = session.createQuery(query, String.class).stream();
        Long max = ids
                .map(o -> o.replace(valuePrefix, ""))
                .mapToLong(value -> Long.parseLong(value))
                .max()
                .orElse(0L);

        return valuePrefix + String.format(numberFormat, (max + 1));
    }

}
```

And the Product entity :

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "product_seq")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "product_seq",
            strategy = "com.example.jpa.entity.StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "P"),
                    @Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%05d")
            })

    private String id;
    
    // Constructor, getters and setters
}
```

Result :

[image: Result in database]